# Coding numerical derivatives in R

Tags: r

I am totally new to R and I am struggling to write a code to find the numerical derivatives of vector fields. I have two matrices U and V, e.g.,

`U <- matrix(runif(9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = T)`

`V <- matrix(runif(9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = T)`

These matrices (not actual values obviously) represents the components of a 2D wind vector field. I would like to code the numerical derivatives of the 2 vector components `du/dy` and `dv/dx`. I have no idea how to do this in R. Please help. Sorry in advance if this question has been answered already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `diff()` function. You can apply it efficiently  over a dimension of a matrix using an apply

```
U <- matrix(runif(9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = T) #Your wind component

apply(U,2,diff) #change the '1' by '2' to apply diff over the other dim
```

Hope this helped.